# Cannot create shell objects

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, com

I cant seem to create any shell related object while scripting asp.net web page with VB

```
Server.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
```

and

```
CreateObject("shell.application")
```

seems to return same error message. I believe I have done something wrong that I am not aware of. Can anybody please point where I am going wrong?

It gives the following error message

> The component 'shell.application' cannot be created.  Apartment threaded components can only be created on pages with an `<%@ Page aspcompat=true %>` page directive.
>
> The component 'Wscript.Shell' cannot be created.  Apartment threaded components can only be created on pages with an `<%@ Page aspcompat=true %>` page directive.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN Article for COM Component Compatibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk9h2kb(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
<%@ Page AspCompat="true" Language="VB" %>

<script runat="server">
    Dim WshShell = Server.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    Protected Sub doStuff(strCommand, cliint)
        Select Case cliint
            Case "cmd"
                strCommand = "%SYSTEMROOT%\cmd.exe /c " & strCommand & " 2>&1 %SYSTEMROOT%\Logs\some_kind_of.log"
            Case "ps"
                'will obviously require you modify execution policies...
                strCommand = "%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe " & strCommand & " 2>&1 %SYSTEMROOT%\Logs\some_kind_of.log"
            Case else
        End Select
        WshShell.Run(strCommand)
    End Sub
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now I'm not getting any error but still I can't use objects with shell.application to use the GetDetailsOf function. Can you pls help me with the shell.application problem?

Comment: @IshaqSheikMohamed That's a different question.

Comment: @Lankymart I have specified that I am facing problem with two things. I am not able to find any solution elsewhere